# Azure Web App server side exception displays blank page

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET web forms app, running on Azure as an Azure Web App. When it throws an exception the user sees a blank page. Looking at the network log in the browser, the browser receives a response from the server of HTTP200.

Having customErrors set to On or Off in the web.config makes no difference.

I have tested this by deliberately throwing an exception in page load. When I run/debug my app locally in Visual Studio all works as expected, if customErrors is On then I get redirected to my error page, if it is Off I see exception details in the browser.

Why is Azure just showing me a blank page in this scenario?

Comment: Can you check the variables that you have on the webapp on azure portal they would override your web.config parameters.

Comment: Have checked there, nothing that would effect customErrors.

Answer (score 0):

Two actions can be tested:

1. Please enable the Remote debugging feature on Azure and use this feature to find the error message.And debug the `application_error` method on `Global.asax`
2. please share more details about your `web.config error message section` or how to handle the error message if you handled the error message using code.

Any information or update, please let me know.